# What's the chance that a number randomly drawn from a set of numbers is bigger than one drawn before it?

Tags: probability

It has been a long time since last I opened a book on probability/statistics, so this might actually be a very basic question.

Let's say I have a set $S = \{1, 2, \cdots, 5000\}$. Clearly, $S$ has 5000 elements.
Now, I select a number randomly from $S$ and remove it (I reassign $S = S\backslash\{a^0\}$), where I'm calling the number $a^0$. Now, $S$ has 4999 elements.

If I select and then remove a second number at random, called $a^*$, what is the probability that $a^* > a^0$?

---

So, after removing $a^0$, we have 4999 elements in the set. The chance that a number in the set is greater than $a^0$ will be

$$
P(a^*>a^0)= \dfrac{\mbox{number of elements greater than $a^0$}}{\mbox{number of elements remaining}} = \dfrac{\mbox{number of elements greater than $a^0$}}{4999}
$$

Let's try a simpler example, $T = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

```
I pick | P(a^*>a^0)
     1 | 1
     2 | 2/3
     3 | 1/3
     4 | 0
```

---

I thought about looking at the expected value as well.

$$
E(X) = \sum xP(x) = x_0 P(x_0) + x_1 P(x_1) + \cdots + x_n P(x_n)
$$

Applying this to the diminished set, we have
$$
E(S) = \sum aP(a) = a_0P(a_0) + \cdots + a_{5000}P(a_{5000})
$$

Now, $P(a_i) = 1/4999$ for all $i = 1,\cdots,5000$ except for when $i=i^0 \implies a_{i^{0}} = a^0 \implies P(a_{i^{0}}) = 0$.

So a rough estimate of the expectation is $E(S) = \frac{1}{4999}\sum_{k=1}^{5000} k = 5001 \times 2500 \div 4999 \approx 2501.00020004$. Obviously, this is quite far off. For example, $a^0 = 5000$ means that we will have an error in our expectation greater than $1$!

---

I'm editing because there were a lot of comments and I think I was unclear.

When selecting the first number $a^0$, each number has probability $1/5000$ of being drawn. Hence, the expected value drawn is $(1+2+\cdots+5000)/5000 = 2500\times5001\div5000 = 5001/2$ (using the definition of the expectation). This was mentioned by André Nicolas below.

But remember: I remove $a^0$ after drawing it, so the size of the set decreases by 1.

So now I'll draw for the second time, from the set with $a^0$ removed.

Each number still in the set has probability $1/4999$ of being drawn. But our sum in the numerator is missing $a^0$.

So the expected value is $(1+2+\cdots+5000 - a^0)/4999$. Is there a way of making this value more explicit?

---

Sorry if you think I'm being obtuse; I just really don't get it!

Comment: You are basically choosing two numbers $a^0$ and $a^{*}$ from $S$ and asking what the probability is that $a^0<a^{*}$. Wouldn't it just be $1/2$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ervx: You are not missing anything $-$ the answer to the first question is obviously $\frac12$. But I don't understand the second part: the expected value of what, exactly?

Comment: @TonyK I was looking at the expected value of the next number I would draw, namely $a^*$. To be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing as probability is not really my thing and the last time I did any was years ago. (^_^;)

Comment: @ervx I can accept that it would be $1/2$, but I'm not really sure I could write a proof showing that...

Comment: The expected value of the second number is the same as the expected value of the first, $(1+\cdots+5000)/5000$, exactly $5001/2$.

Comment: If you really want a proof by using formulas then you can use the law of total probability.

Comment: Well, you are just taking to elements at random. One will always be larger than the other. You can think about it as though you are drawing them simultaneously.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Perhaps I was unclear or maybe my question doesn't actually make sense. I see that the first number I select can be any of $1,2,\cdots,5000$ so the expected value is as you said $5001/2$. But, once I select my first number I remove it from the set. So now I have $4999$ numbers to choose from. So when making my second choice, each possible number has probability $1/4999$ of being drawn. But I don't know which number I drew first, so I can't modify the sum in the numerator...

Comment: We could calculate the long way, taking account of all possible first numbers. I could do it, it takes a few lines. After some unpleasantness and simplification, we would end up at $5001/2$. It is much easier to note that the second number is equally likely to be any of $1,2,\dots,5000$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability is $\frac12$ by symmetry. Since all numbers are by assumption equiprobable, for each pair you have the same probability of drawing first the one number and then the other or vice versa.